# Methods no longer exist when sending to/from ipcRenderer

Tags: javascript, electron

I have the following in my render process:

```
class Component {
    findClosestComponent(c) { /* Do stuff */ }
}

class Item extends Component {
    download() {
        this.myProperty = 123;
        ipcRenderer.send('download-game', this);
        ipcRenderer.on('download-complete', (evt, dl) => {
            console.log(dl.myProperty);
            dl.findClosestComponent(GameCard);
        });
    }
}
```

I then have this in my main process:

```
ipcMain.on('download-game', (evt, dl) => {
    /* Download the file the send back the object */
    evt.sender.send('download-complete', dl);
});
```

When I execute the `download()` method, it sends the current object to the main process, and then the main process sends it back. When I try to access the method `findClosestComponent()` it is no longer there. However, when I try to access the property `myProperty` it does exist and prints out.

How can I send the object to the main process then get it back and access the methods?

Comment: i think it is json serialized, which is why your properties still exist but not functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron's `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` modules serialize the message to JSON before sending it, so if you want to get a better idea of what actually gets sent between processes put the message through `JSON.stringify()`. Functions/methods and prototype chains won't make it across the process boundry, if you want that to work you'll have to implement your own serialization/deserialization scheme.

Comment: that makes me sad :( I have a download button, and if I click download for 2 different items, the event fires at the same time for both buttons... the `download` gets fired on a click event, so is there anyway to catch which button was clicked?